# using globalCompositeOperation with lines?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I'm trying to make a clock with HTML 5's canvas element.

What i'm trying to do is make a line for every second, and then erase the previous line.

I want to erase the previous line with drawing another line using the `globalCompositeOperation='xor';` but it doesn't work!

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Clock</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="spin()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
    var firstTime = 0;
    var prevX=null;
    var prevY=null;

    function spin() {
        //get the canvas element
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //get the right angle for the clock hand
        var date = new Date;
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        var a = seconds*6;
        var angleRadian = a*Math.PI/180;
        var angle = 1/2*Math.PI - angleRadian;

        if(a > 360)
            a = 0; 
        //Erase the previous line, if it has been drawn.
        if(prevX!=null)
            erasePrevLine(angle, canvas, context);
        //draw line
        drawLine(angle, 100, canvas, context);
        //repeat for the next second
        setTimeout(spin, 500);
    }
    function drawLine(angle, radius, canvas, context)   {
        var centerX = canvas.width/2;
        var centerY = canvas.height/2;

        var xTarget = centerX + Math.cos(angle)*radius;
        var yTarget = centerY - Math.sin(angle)*radius;

        //save this state to be erased
        prevX = xTarget;
        prevY = yTarget;

        //draw
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        context.lineTo(xTarget, yTarget);
        context.stroke();
    }
    function erasePrevLine(angle, canvas, context)  {
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
        var centerX = canvas.width/2;
        var centerY = canvas.height/2;
        prevAngle = angle + (Math.PI/180*6);
        var xTarget = prevX;
        var yTarget = prevY;

        //draw on the previous line
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        context.lineTo(xTarget, yTarget );
        context.stroke();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/pyerT/1/
Anybody knows the answer? it works fine with shapes and texts..

Comment: Willing to help...any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

globalCompositeOperation (xor) will not work on a **rotating** line like a “clock hand”….here’s why:

Assume you draw a vertical line.  Then draw a second vertical line to the right of the first.  Assume the second vertical line **overlaps** the first line by half.

Canvas.globalCompositeOperation=”xor” causes overlapping areas to be removed, so the second line removes **half** the first line and also half of itself.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/e24KU/

```
    function drawLine(){
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="xor";
        ctx.strokeStyle="red";
        ctx.lineWidth=10;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(posX,10);
        ctx.lineTo(posX,100);
        ctx.stroke();
        posX+=5;
    }
```

This is a Fiddle of a “clock hand” sweeping around a centerpoint:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hW2EY/

However, if we try to use “xor” on a rotating line, the lines overlay **at an angle** and therefore the xor is incomplete.

Here is a Fiddle showing the line “xor” being ineffective when rotated:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/f7hHx/

**[Edited: new code was supplied by OP allowing for an expanded answer]**

I looked at your new code and am suggesting some changes and optimizations.

As I said in my original answer,  you *cannot* effectively erase a line that was drawn at an angle.  This is due to anti-aliasing that the browser does automatically—antiAliasing for canvas cannot be turned off.

Here is a Fiddle of the results after the changes:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9QD65/

Changes:

**Believe it or not:** It is usual to completely erase and completely redraw the canvas during each animation loop!  Canvas really is quick enough to handle these redraws—especially now that canvas is GPU accelerated.  If you *absolutely* need to optimize your performance, you *can* define “dirty” areas of the canvas that must be erased/redrawn and leave the other areas as previously drawn.  In practice, once you need this type of performance, your canvas is so complicated that it’s more efficient to completely clear/redraw than to try to define the dirty areas.

Optimizations:

Moved canvas,context,centerX,centerY out of the animation loop since these values can be computed once and reused.

Here is my suggested code for you to look at:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Clock</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="spin()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
    var firstTime = 0;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX=canvas.width/2;
    var centerY=canvas.height/2;
    var canvasWidth=canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight=canvas.height;

    function spin() {
        //get the right angle for the clock hand
        var date = new Date;
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        var a = seconds*6;
        var angleRadian = a*Math.PI/180;
        var angle = 1/2*Math.PI - angleRadian;

        if(a > 360)
            a = 0; 
        //draw line
        drawLine(angle, 100, canvas, context, "black",1);
        //repeat for the next second
        setTimeout(spin, 500);
    }

    function drawLine(angle, radius, canvas, context)   {
        var xTarget = centerX + Math.cos(angle)*radius;
        var yTarget = centerY - Math.sin(angle)*radius;

        //clear the canvas
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

        //draw
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        context.lineTo(xTarget, yTarget);
        context.stroke();
        context.restore()
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But my problem is that `globalCompositeOperation` seems unable to 'xor' two lines.. I've added my simplified code, if you wan't to take a look.

Comment: Whoa, thanks a lot! it really helps. Thank you! I never thought about drawing a whole new canvas before :)

Comment: More great stuff!  Ahem, but can't you redraw using XOR the original clock hand and then increment the position?  That is to say always draw the same line twice: once to make it appear and once to remove.